# Dynamic TableViewCell | Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, tableview, cell, uitableview

I have 2 custom cells: 1 for image, 2 for text (using label to display).
I want text-cell to be dynamic height, depending on text size.
Set lines of label to 0, used top, left and right constraints, but when i add info to array, reload it - then table displays nothing.
Also in viewDidLoad coded next:

```
    articleTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
    articleTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    if content[indexPath.row].rangeOfString("imageBase64") == nil  {

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell

        cell.textArticle.text = content[indexPath.row] as String

    }
    else{

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        cell.imageArticle.image = decodedImage

    }

    return UITableViewCell()

}
```

[image]

What's the problem here?

Comment: No bottom constraint?

Comment: you must write some code, otherwise we play the lottery

Comment: what code you want me to write? @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: First of all cellForRowAtIndexPath , then if you use sizeToFit in your labels, also you can post some screenshots about all constraints..it's too minimal

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano added

Comment: That's useless code. Why do you return a default `UITableViewCell` instead of the custom ones?

Comment: @vadian because it depends on what cell i want to call

Comment: You have to write `return cell` at the end of the `if - else` branches respectively and delete the last line. Consider that at the moment you're returning a generic default cell ignoring the custom cells.

Comment: @vadian thank you! it helped, but now it gives "Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead."

Comment: The message of the warning is pretty clear.

Comment: @vadian thank you so much! solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return cell` not `return UITableViewCell()`